# Browsers lazy-loading fonts with FontFace

Tags: javascript, font-face, cssom

So, I'm developing a simple web game with the Canvas API. I need to draw characters in the canvas using specified fonts.

In the loading routine, I use promises to wait for the fonts I need, like this:

```
Promise.all([
    (new FontFace("LCD Solid", "url('assets/LCD_Solid.ttf')")).load().then((font)=>{
        document.fonts.add(font)
    }, (err)=>{
        throw {type: "font_loading_err", fontName: "LCD Solid", DOMException: err}
    }),
    (new FontFace("Conformity", "url('assets/Conformity.ttf')")).load().then((font)=>{
        document.fonts.add(font)
    }, (err)=>{
        throw {type: "font_loading_err", fontName: "Conformity", DOMException: err}
    }),
]).then(loadGame, oops)
```

The promises are resolved, but not loaded. Chrome and Firefox only load them when I use `fillText()`, originating some frames with the default serif font, until the font loads, in Chrome.

According to [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/#font-face-load) the promises should only be resolved when the fonts are loaded, but it also allows for lazy loading.

Is there any way to avoid lazy-loading the fonts and force the browser to load them at that moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [FontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) could work well for you here. You can still load the fonts using the JS API or the usual `@font-face` CSS API, and FontFaceObserver will help you trigger something else when the font has loaded.

Here’s a full example combining your code and the multiple fonts example from the FontFaceObserver README:

```html
<canvas id="js-canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fontfaceobserver@2.1.0/fontfaceobserver.standalone.js"></script>
<script>
var exampleFontData = {
  'Family A': { weight: 400, src: 'url(assets/FamilyA-Regular.woff2), url(assets/FamilyA-Regular.woff)' },
  'Family B': { weight: 400, src: 'url(assets/FamilyB-Regular.otf)' },
  // Etc.
}

var observers = []
var fonts = []

// Make one Observer along with each font
Object.keys(exampleFontData).forEach(function(family) {
  var data = exampleFontData[family]
  var obs = new FontFaceObserver(family, data)
  var font = new FontFace(family, data.src)

  observers.push(obs.load())
  fonts.push(
    font
      .load()
      .then((f) => {
        document.fonts.add(f)
      }, (err) => {
        throw {type: "font_loading_err", fontName: family, DOMException: err}
      })
  )
})

Promise.all(fonts)
.then(() => {
  console.log('Use the canvas')
  var canvas = document.getElementById('js-canvas')
  canvas.width = 750
  canvas.height = 500
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  ctx.font = '36px "Family A"'
  ctx.fillText('HELLO USING FONT', 20, 50)

  ctx.font = '36px "Family B"'
  ctx.fillText('Hello using font', 20, 150)
}, (err) => {
  console.error(err)
})
</script>
```

[image: Result of using the fonts on the canvas.]

Hope that’s helpful!